# How do I delete a Git branch locally?

Tags: git

i wanted to delete git branch locally but i get the error

```
$ git branch -d remotes/origin/incident
error: branch 'remotes/origin/incident' not found.
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: remotes/origin ==> its not local branch, execute, $git branch command , identify the branch name you want to delete then execute: $git branch -d <localBranchName>, to forcedelete use: $git branch -D <localBranchName>, hope this will help: https://git-scm.com/docs,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are specifying remote branch. you need to specify local branch

```
git branch -d incident
```